# Python: Why "2 in [1,2,3] == True" returns False?

Tags: python, boolean-expression

Suppose I enter this in Shell, then I get True .

```
>>>ar=[2,4,6,8]
>>>2 in ar
True
```

But when I try to use this, it doesn't work

```
>>>if 2 in ar==True:
       print("YES")

>>> 
>>>
```

It doesn't work! The if condition is False. What can I do to check whether a term is there in a list with a loop?
For example: I am given some random list and I have to print all the even numbers present in the list?

Comment: You don't need the `==True`, just use `if 2 in ar`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is because with comparison operators, `x operator1 y operator2 z` is equivalent to `(x operator1 y) and (y operator2 z)` except that `y` is evaluated only once.  Therefore `2 in ar == True` is equivalent to `(2 in ar) and (ar == True)`.  `ar == True` is False, so the `if` block is not executed.  Just put parentheses around `2 in ar`: `if (2 in ar) == True:`  You really don't need the `== True`, though.  Just do `if 2 in ar:`.